# How does class Application(frame): works?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have  a question. I thought that a class can be based on an object or previously define class. When I change it into class Application(object): it doesn't work. Can you tell me why it didn't work and why did the code below works or why did class Application(Frame) works? Frame is not a previously define object and not object. Sorry for my English. Here is my code:

```
# Lazy Buttons
# Demonstrates using a class with tkinter

from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame): #
    """ A GUI application with three buttons. """
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """  Create three buttons that do nothing. """
        # create the first Button
        self.bttn1 = Button(self, text= "I do nothing.")
        self.bttn1.grid()

        # create second button
        self.bttn2 = Button(self)
        self.bttn2.grid()
        self.bttn2.configure(text="Me too!")

        # create third button
        self.bttn3 = Button(self)
        self.bttn3.grid()
        self.bttn3["text"] = "Same here!"

# main
root= Tk()
root.title("Lazy Buttons")
root.geometry("200x85")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Frame` is a previously defined class. It's part of `tkinter`, which you imported on your first line.

Your `Application` class extends `Frame`, which means that it gets methods from `Frame` and can do everything that a Tk Frame can do, like show widgets. If you don't extend `Frame`, and only extend `object` instead, this will not work.

It might be clearer to replace...

```
from tkinter import *
```

with...

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and fix your references to Tk's classes (they would become tk.Button, tk.Frame and tk.Tk).

Comment: @JohnCruz: Also see [Why is “import *” bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/4014959)